# Div tag displaying content in new line

Tags: css, html

I have code that looks like this:

```
<h4 class="tableTotals">Total Selected: R<div id="bankTotal">##,##</div></h4>
```

The output that I want should all be in ONE line but as it turns out the div tags displays it's content in a new line, which I don't exactly want. So the output looks like this:

```
Total Selected: R
##,##
```

When I actually want it to display like this:

```
Total Selected: R##,##
```

Does anybody know how to stop the div displaying on a new line?
Thank for any push in the right direction!

Comment: Div's are block elements, you could set the display style to in-line or just use the proper element such as a span.

Comment: BTW, `DL/DT/DD` would be probably more appropriate: `<dl><dt>Total Selected:</dt><dd>R##,##</dd></dl>`.

Comment: Never knew about the span tag, very helpful tag to know I'm sure. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<span>` instead of `<div>`

div is a block element, and h4 is a header meant for single line.

Comment: "h4 is a header meant for single line" 
AFAIK, headers are block elements, but that doesn't mean they must have only one line.

Answer (score 3):

Style your div to be displayed as `inline-block`

```
#bankTotal { display: inline-block; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/xVmDB/)

Using `inline-block` does not have to chang the `div` completely into as `inline` element just like `span` . Furthermore, you can still have block properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div> is a block element and will put a return before and after the <div>
```

You should use  instead.

```
<h4 class="tableTotals">Total Selected: R<span id="bankTotal">##,##</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS:

```
#bankTotal{
   display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

div displaying on a new line ?

```
<div id="bankTotal" style="display:inline">##,##</div>
```

or

```
<div id="bankTotal" style="float:left">##,##</div>
```

but better :

```
<span id="bankTotal"  >##,##</span >
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline` property of css for displaying the div "inline",
or u could use `<span>` tag instead of `<div>` tag ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<h4 class="tableTotals" style="display:inline;">Total Selected: R<div id="bankTotal" style="float:left;">##,##</div></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added a style to position the DIV manually to where you want it to be. Please note that I didn't put it in its exact position so just fiddle with the margin PX.

```
<h4 class="tableTotals">Total Selected: R<div id="bankTotal" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:-10px;">##,##</div></h4>
```